# Cannot connect (SMB nor NFS) from wifi to wired on LAN - Arris router (Cox)

Tags: router, nfs, lan, gateway

Windows/Linux on WiFi side of LAN can use port 80/web sites on my Linux server on wired side of LAN, but not NFS shares or SMB shares (Samba).
Is my Arris router blocking the traffic?  If both/all systems are wired, everything works/connects. Does anyone know how to make file sharing work?

Comment: Did you check the firewall on the linux server? Did you check SELinux settings?